# R Shiny CondtionalPanel not using CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, r, shiny, rpivottable

I'm using R Shiny to build a web application.

I'm using conditionPanels to (sometimes) show a pivot table depending on the type of object `df`.

As shown below, if the pivot table is shown within a conditionalpanel, the css is simply ignored and the Pivot table is shown in default style. But if I include a second pivottable, not rendered in the conditionalpanel, both pivottables are in the style as described in the custom.css.

How can I make sure that the stylesheet is used for the first pivottable when there is not second one?

```
# Server.R
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  df <- data.frame(col1 = c('a','b','c'),
                   col2 = c(1,2,3))

  ## Output PivotTable
  output$pivotTable <- rpivotTable::renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(data = df,
                aggregatorName = 'Sum',
                rendererName = 'Table')
  })

  ## Output PivotTable2
  output$pivotTable2 <- rpivotTable::renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(data = df,
                aggregatorName = 'Sum',
                rendererName = 'Table')
  })

  condition <- ifelse(is.data.frame(df), 'true', 'false')

  ## Output PivotTable
  output$panelTable <- renderUI({
    conditionalPanel(
      condition,
      rpivotTableOutput("pivotTable")
    )
  })
})



# UI.R:
ui <- dashboardPage(
  title = "",

  ## Header content + dropdownMenu
  dashboardHeader(
    title = tags$b(""),
    titleWidth = 250
  ),

  ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 250,
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("tab1", tabName = "tab", icon = icon("table"))
    )
  ),

  ## Body content
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "tab",
        div(
          uiOutput('panelTable')
        ),
        div(
          rpivotTableOutput("pivotTable2")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

CSS:

```
/* Adjust css of pivot table */
#pivotTable{ 
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.pvtRows, .pvtCols {
  background: #FAFAFA none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

table.pvtTable tbody tr th, table.pvtTable thead tr th {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.pvtAxisContainer li span.pvtAttr {
    background: rgba(147,255,53,0.8);
}
```

Comment: Hi did any of the answer help you?  Or is the problem still unsolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI your problem is that your css is being overruled from css rules generated be pivotTable to over rule this add `!important` after each rule like this

```
#pivotTable{ 
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.pvtRows, .pvtCols {
  background: #FAFAFA none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
}

table.pvtTable tbody tr th, table.pvtTable thead tr th {
  background: #FFFFFF!important;
}

.pvtAxisContainer li span.pvtAttr {
    background: rgba(147,255,53,0.8) !important;
}
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to define class inside the div's.

For example:

```
div(class = "pvtRows pvtAxisContainer",
  uiOutput('panelTable')
)
```